# Subset range of data of type 'double'

Tags: r, double, subset

**Problem is solved in the comments!**

I have a list (called '`Spec_opt`') of 9 elements (`S3 Spectra`). Two of these elements ('`data`' and '`freq`') are of the data type `'double'` (see attached screen dump).

Calling `Spec_opt$freq[1:5]` looks like this:

```
> Spec_opt$freq[1:5]
[1] 19.65228 19.65205 19.65183 19.65160 19.65137
```

I need to subset the range of these values and I have tried:

```
Spec_opt$freq <- Spec_opt$freq %>% filter(Spec_opt$freq %in% (-0.5:9.5))
```

But get this error:

```
Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

This:

```
Spec_opt$freq <- Spec_opt$freq[which(Spec_opt$freq >= -.5 | Spec_opt$freq <= 9.5)]
```

Doesn't do a thing.

From other posts I have learned that it is the data type (`'double'`) which is the issue.

Doing this: `Spec_opt$freq <- lapply(Spec_opt$freq, as.numeric)` ,

converts `Spec_opt$freq` into a list where each element is still of the type 'double'

Calling Spec_opt$freq[1:5] now looks like this:

```
Spec_opt$freq[1:10]
[[1]]
[1] 19.65228

[[2]]
[1] 19.65205

[[3]]
[1] 19.65183

[[4]]
[1] 19.6516

[[5]]
[1] 19.65137
```

Can someone help me either, convert the `'double'` into "normal" `values` OR help me subset the data when it is in this format?

I am sorry, I don't know how to provide the data, if I call `dput(Spec_opt$freq[1:50])` to provide a subset (total n = 130,000 values), it just gives a list of numbers, where the issue is not 'passed along' so to say...

```
> dput(Spec_opt$freq[1:5])
c(19.6522802209025, 19.6520531555891, 19.6518260902757, 19.6515990249622, 
19.6513719596488)
```

The entire `Spec_opt` object is very large and `dput(Spec_opt)` can't be printed in my 'window'. 
Let me know if I can make this example better?

[image]

Comment: I also sometimes see this error. Often there is another package loaded which masks the `filter` function from `dplyr`. Can you try `dplyr::filter`?

Comment: Like this: Spec_opt$freq <- Spec_opt$freq %>% dplyr::filter(Spec_opt$freq %in% (-.5:9.5)) - That gives the same error message.

Comment: Try: `Spec_opt$freq[Spec_opt$freq >= -.5 & Spec_opt$freq <= 9.5]`

Comment: Can you check if `filter(Spec_opt, dplyr::between(freq, -0.5, 9.5))` gives what you want ?

Comment: @GKi that totally worked! - aargh such a stupid little ting '&' in stead of '|'. Thank you so much for seeing the error!

Comment: @RonakShah it didn't - says 'no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "Spectra"'. And if I change it to: filter(Spec_opt$freq, dplyr::between(freq, -0.5, 9.5)), I get same error as before. BTW. how do you guys format your writting in the comments? - to distinguish between code and text?

Comment: @Mathilde please see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77491/476780)

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with some of the errors is to convert your list into a data frame, and then apply the filter:

```
library(dplyr)


Spec_opt <- list(freq =c(19.6522802209025, 19.6520531555891, 19.6518260902757, 19.6515990249622, 19.6513719596488))

Spec_opt <-  as.data.frame(Spec_opt) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(freq > -0.5, freq < 9.5)
```

Also:

> Spec_opt$freq <- Spec_opt$freq[which(Spec_opt$freq >= -.5 |
>   Spec_opt$freq <= 9.5)]

This wouldn't work since you are using an OR statement, which basically, says: "keep everything larger or equal to -0.5, or everything smaller or equal to 9.5", which is an infinite range of numbers.

Comment: Hi, sorry I should have made that clear, Spec_opt$freq is 130,000 values ranging from ca. -10 to 19.

Comment: Okay. Does converting it into a data frame solve the problem? The data frame can always be converted back to a list

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** saw @GKis comment too late.

Please see the following example for subsetting / splitting vectors in a `list()`:

```
Spec_opt <- list()
Spec_opt$freq <- as.double(seq(-10, 19, 0.01))

# subset data
subset1 <- Spec_opt$freq[Spec_opt$freq >= 18 & Spec_opt$freq < 18.5]
subset2 <- Spec_opt$freq[Spec_opt$freq >= 18.5 & Spec_opt$freq < 19]

# split data
split(Spec_opt$freq, cut(Spec_opt$freq, breaks = c(17, 17.5, 18, 18.5, 19)))
```